# List<String> to String in C#

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity

I made some tables in Entity Framework 5.0 and generated an SQL Server Database from it. The tables are as follows:

```
Title (TitleId, TitleName, TitlePrice, ISBN...)
Author (AuthorId, FirstName, LastName)
Category (CategoryId, CategoryName)
```

The relationships between Title and Author and Title and Category are many to many.

Now, here is how I access what categories are assigned to each title and what authors have contributed to a title.

```
//for authors
var queryAuthList = from au in ebs.Authors
                            from t in au.Titles
                            where t.TitleId == TitleId
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = string.Concat(au.FirstName, " ", au.LastName)
                            };

//for categories
var queryCatList = from cat in ebs.Categories
                           from t in cat.Titles
                           where t.TitleId == TitleId
                           select new
                           {
                               cat.CategoryName
                           };
```

Now, how do I display the contents of queryAuthList or queryCatList in a simple text label?

I want the output to be like `AuthorA, AuthorB, AuthorC` for authors and `CategoryX, CategoryY, CategoryZ` for categories assigned to a single title.

I tried declaring a `List<String>` and adding the items to the list in a `foreach` loop, and then printing the list using `String.Join(",",strList)`. However the output appears as

`{Name = AuthorA}, {Name = AuthorB}, {Name = AuthorC}
 {CategoryName = CategoryX}, {CategoryName = CategoryY}, {CategoryName = CategoryZ}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{Name = AuthorA}` you see is the default `ToString()` for an anonymous type.

You don't want that, so do not wrap it in a anonymous type:

```
var queryAuthList = from au in ebs.Authors
                            from t in au.Titles
                            where t.TitleId == TitleId
                            //select new
                            //{
                            //    Name = string.Concat(au.FirstName, " ", au.LastName)
                            //};
                            select string.Concat(au.FirstName, " ", au.LastName);
```

And since `queryAuthList` now is an `IEnumerable<string>`,

```
 string result = String.Join(",", queryAuthList);
```